# Remove dots and commas from numbers in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress

In a Wordpress MySQL database, in `wp_postmeta table`, there are most rows with `meta_key='price'` and with `meta_value='XXX'` where XXX is a number.
 The meta_value is a long text field. The numbers stored in it have a different shape some are stored with a dot, meaning thousand (10.000 means ten thousand) others are stored with a comma, meaning hundredth (10,00 means ten).
 How to remove dots and comma so to have a pure number, without hundredth? In other words, 100.000 should be 100000 and 10,00 should be 10
 Thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try a global [**REPLACE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET meta_value = REPLACE(REPLACE(meta_value,',00',''),'.','')
WHERE meta_key='price';
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, your code works well for dots, but numbers like 160,00 become 16000, instead I need 160 as right value.

Comment: Do you have a copy of the table ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful about how you do this.  I would suggest checking for '.' or ',' at the end of the string.  This requires looking at the third character from the end:

```
update wp_postmeta
    set meta_value = (case when left(right(meta_value, 3), 1) = '.'
                           then replace(meta_value, ',', '')
                           when left(right(meta_value, 3), 1) = ','
                           then replace(meta_value, '.', '')
                           else replace(replace(meta_value, ',', ''), '.', '')
                      end)
    where meta_key = 'price'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have the following error with your query: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= (case when left(right(meta_value, 3), 1)) = '.'
                       then r' at line 2`

Comment: @GordonLinoff I didn't look too closely but you may want to do another level of checks, some countries do 5.000.88 (or 5 000,88) versus 5,000.88

Comment: Apologies.  I don't have mysql handy here.  But, fortunately, the syntax for this is the same as for SQL Server.  So, adding in the "set" after the update and replacing a comma with a left paren did the trick.

Comment: @GordonLinoff now it works, but values with comma like 135,00 now are 13500 that is not correct, because I need 135

Comment: I misunderstand what you want.  Do you want 100,000 to be 100000 or do you want 10,000 to be 10?  You question is ambiguous and I chose the first one.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding probably due to American or European notation difference, however I need the second one.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to loop through the rows in the database and just remove the .'s and remove the ,'s and the next two characters after them.

I don't understand why you're using the symbols backwards though.

Also, be careful as modifying the database can change how WordPress interprets the data.

Comment: What means that you don't understand the using of symbols backwards? Can you give me an example? Thank you.

Comment: Typically (at least in america) a comma ',' is used to seperate between ones, thousands, millions, billions and such (i.e one million would be 1,000,000) and decimal points '.' are used to seperate the whole numbers from the decimal portion of numbers (i.e. 5 and 3/10 would be 5.3)

Comment: As you said, this is true in America. Here in Europe the dot is used for thousands and comma for decimals.

Comment: Learn something new every day I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Try REPLACE:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, '.', '') WHERE meta_key='price';
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, ',', '') WHERE meta_key='price'
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Use at your own risk.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, your code works well for dots, but numbers like 160,00 become 16000, instead I need 160 as right value.

Comment: @Avionicom then try UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, ',00', '') WHERE meta_key='price'

Comment: OK, now works well, but I noted that some values have three 0 after the comma, for example 135,000 How I can do?

Comment: @Avionicom Are you asking how to handle them or how to remove the comma?

Comment: first of all thank you for the help. I'm asking how to remove the comma and all the zeros over there. In other words, all the comma and decimals have to be removed.

Comment: Then just replacing the comma and decimals with nothing (as answered) should resolve your issue.